# Read data from file without using perform until and at end

Tags: cobol

I am trying to read data using Cobol with following the restriction

NOT allowed to use :

AT END clause

PERFORM-UNTIL

IF-ELSE

Switch case statement

Iteration Statement

```
   002-READ.
        READ d-attendance
        IF (?????)
           perform  002-READ
        END-IF.
```

I am trying to simulate a loop with code above but i don't know how I should write the IF statement, is there any way to detect EOF without using AT END?

Comment: Use a file status, see http://www.simotime.com/cblrtn01.htm or google **file status in cobol example**. also try **Goto 002-read**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first define your file under `file-control`, you can define it like this:

```
select my-file
    assign to 'ifile.txt'
    organization is line sequential
    file status is fs.
```

now, `fs` variable's value changes when you read from the file. For instance, when no errors are found, `fs` takes the value `00`. More information can be found [here](http://ibmmainframes.com/references/a27.html).

If you are not allowed to use such statements that you have listed, then you can call your function that reads a line recursively until `fs` is not equal to `00`.